# Installing all IIS components with ISES, WKC and Stewardship center on one computer

Tags: ibm-information-server

I need to install all IIS components with ISES, WKC and Stewardship center on one computer

I am wondering if this will be practically possible or not and I listed below my questions to be very clear to understand each missing information for us:Is it possible to install & configure those components (IIS, ISES, WKC and Stewardship center) on one node/machine ?

If yes, What's the suitable hardware sizing and allocated resources needed for this node?

If no, what is the suggested hardware sizing and allocated resources considered minimum dedicated nodes/resources for that PoC ?

On other hand, I did many IIS installation with different standard topologies on only premises environment, it's nice to have from your experiences any documents or links describe above products installation, tips and steps

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a minimum of 2 VMs/Servers because the Microservices Tier (WKC) has to be on its own VM/Server.

You can put the Stewardship Center, Engine, Repository and Services Tiers in 1 VM/Server.

Minimum Configuration will be 16 Cores and 64GB RAM for Microservices Tier and 4 Cores with 32GB RAM for the others.

What do you plan to do with Stewardship Center? In V11.7.1 Activiti is provided as another option for workflow and it is part of the Microservices Tier.

What PoC are you planning to do?